# Parent/Child class hierachy in nodejs

Tags: node.js, class, ecmascript-6

**child.js**

```
class Child {
  constructor(){
    this.helloWorld = "Hello World";
  }
  run() {
  }
}

export default new Child();
```

**parent.js**

```
import child from './child.js';
class Parent {
  constructor() {
     this.child = child;
  }
}

export default new Parent();
```

**index.js**

```
import parent from './parent.js'

console.log(parent.child.helloWorld);  <-- does not throws an error, displays "Hello World"
console.log(parent.child.run);  <-- throws an error (Cannot read property run from undefined)
console.log(parent.child.run());  <-- throws an error (Cannot read property run from undefined)
```

---

If I do console.log(parent.child) in index.js, run does not show up, however the property helloWorld does..

How can I have the functions exposed as well? I was hoping to be able to do this to help keep my code a bit more organized, so was going to separate it out into separate classes to help minimize the amount of code in each file.

Comment: To be clear: The error you seem to get has nothing to do with `run` not appearing in the `console.log` output.

Comment: let me rephrase it.. child exists, i can see the property "helloWorld", but not the function "run" even tho they both exist in the class, but "run" seems to be hidden, so if I did console.log(parent.child.helloWorld), it does not throw an error

Comment: You've got a spelling error. You've got the parent's constructor spelled as `constuctor`. It should work fine if you fix that.

Comment: And when you call `console.log(parent.child.run)`, you get an error? What's the error? You are providing conflicting information which makes it difficult to find out what's actually going on.

Comment: I made adjustments to post, sorry if I wasn't clear, its an odd issue, lemme try this in jsfiddle and see if i can reproduce it

Comment: What you posted is simply not possible. Do you understand what "Cannot read property run from undefined" means? It means that you are trying to access the property `run` on the value `undefined`. You are trying to access the property `run` on `parent.child`, which means that `parent.child` is `undefined`. But if that's the case then `parent.child.helloWorld` will also throw an error. Wild assumption: Is `run` actually a getter that tries to access the `run` property of another object?

Comment: I'm going to scan through my code and figure out why its acting up, it may just be something in my exports that is causing it, since it seems to be working fine through jsfiddle, going to accept your answer since its lead me toward that direction, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make one thing clear from the start: *The error you seem to get has nothing to do with `run` not appearing in the `console.log` output.*

If your code really throws that error then that means that the value of `parent.child` is `undefined`. Hence when you call `console.log(parent.child)`, you should see `undefined`, not an object. However, I don't see why you'd get that error.

---

Anyways, `run` is defined on the *prototype* of `parent.child`, not on itself. `console.log` most likely shows an object's *own* properties (the console API is not standardized, so results can vary between environments). *That's normal*.

Simple example to reproduce:

```js
var foo = {
  x: 42
};
var bar = Object.create(foo);
bar.y = 21;
console.log(bar, bar.x, bar.y);

// Open the browser console to see output
```

`bar.x` is accessible even though `console.log` doesn't show it (in Chrome at least).

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure if helps you to solve the problem, but whenever I want to add inheritance, I use `extends` and `super` here is an example:

Base Class:

```
class BaseDataModel {
  constructor() {

  }

  getModel() {
     return 'model';
  }

module.exports.BaseDataModel = BaseDataModel;
```

Class extending Base Class:

```
"use strict"
// Imports
const BaseDataModel = require('../baseDataModel').BaseDataModel; // use the proper location
class UserMembershipModel extends BaseDataModel {
  constructor() {
    super(); // this is optional, I use this to inherit the constructors
  }

  getChildModel() {
    return super.getModel(); // This is how you access the function from your extended class
  }
module.exports.UserMembershipModel = UserMembershipModel;
```

Again, not sure if it solves your problem, since your actually adding a property with a Child class. My example is actually extending (or UserMembershipModel inherits from BaseDataModel).

Hope this helps you a bit.